# Dropbox HTTP endpoint is hanging and throwing timeout

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox

Im trying to upload an image through Dropbox HTTP API after authenticating, using NATIVE iOS functions and methods (cannot use ALAMOFIRE). When I send the request it gives me a timeout after 30 seconds.

...Code used:

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image!)
var request = URLRequest.init(url: url)

request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
  "Authorization":"Bearer <TOKEN_HERE>",
  "Dropbox-API-Arg":"{\"path\": \"/TCC/uploaded.png\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": false,\"mute\": false}",
  "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
]

  URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request,
                             from: data) { returnData, response, error in
  guard
    let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200
    else {
      if let callback = failure {
        callback()
      }
      return
  }
  //UI updates in main thread
  DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    if success != nil {
      success!()
    }

  }
  }.resume()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @Danilo Rodrigues,

There is a statement missing, you need to explicitly declare the method used:

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image!)
var request = URLRequest.init(url: url)

request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
  "Authorization":"Bearer <TOKEN_HERE>",
  "Dropbox-API-Arg":"{\"path\": \"/TCC/uploaded.png\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": false,\"mute\": false}",
  "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
]
request.httpMethod = "POST" //ADDED THIS LINE
  URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request,
                             from: data) { returnData, response, error in
  guard
    let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200
    else {
      if let callback = failure {
        callback()
      }
      return
  }
  //UI updates in main thread
  DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    if success != nil {
      success!()
    }

  }
  }.resume()
```